# Unity job system with native collections slower than job system with C# collections

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jobs, entity-component-system

I'm currently working on a simulation that is very CPU heavy and have moved to the job system + burst compiling and could massively increase performance. That said, switching to the job system created a new bottleneck. I wanted to ask if there are any ways to circumvent this.

Here is how my simulation works. It basically moves a 2d rectangle through the worldspace and captures grid coordinates on the path. Without the job, the biggest bottleneck was `SampleLine`, with the job system the bottlenecks are `trajectory.Add`/`.AddNative` and `occupied.IndexOf`.

```
    NativeList<JobHandle> jobHandleList = new NativeList<JobHandle>(Allocator.Temp);
    List<NativeArray<float>> timestampList = new List<NativeArray<float>>();
    List<NativeList<int2>> resultList = new List<NativeList<int2>>();
    while (simulate)
    {
        move(dummy);
        time += timestep;

        NativeArray<float> timestampArr = new NativeArray<float>(1, Allocator.TempJob);
        NativeList<int2> result = new NativeList<int2>(Allocator.TempJob);
        JobHandle jobHandle = GetOccupiedTilesJob(timestep, dummy, grid, ref timestampArr, ref result);
        jobHandleList.Add(jobHandle);
        timestampList.Add(timestampArr);
        resultList.Add(result);
    }

    // get data from jobs and clean up
    JobHandle.CompleteAll(jobHandleList);
    for(int i = 0; i < timestampList.Count; i++)
    {
        // BOTTLENECK HERE
        // TODO: once unity supports it, use resultList[i].ToList()
        /*List<int2> coordinates = new List<int2>();
        for(int j = 0; j < resultList[i].Length; j++)
        {
            coordinates.Add(resultList[i][j]);
        }
        trajectory.Add(timestampList[i][0], coordinates);*/
        trajectory.AddNative(timestampList[i][0], resultList[i]);

        timestampList[i].Dispose();
        resultList[i].Dispose();
    }

    jobHandleList.Dispose();
    return trajectory;
```

`trajectory.Add` uses a `Dictionary<int2, float2>`, and .AddNative uses a `NativeHashMap<int2, float2>` for storing the values. `trajectory.Add` is almost *twice* as fast as AddNative, even though I have to copy all values of the NativeList over to a useless List first. I could probably make it even faster by using an Array as the buffer.

Here is the job used:

```
[BurstCompile]
public struct GetOccupiedTiles : IJob
{
    public float2 A;
    public float2 B;
    public float2 C;
    public float2 D;

    public float timestamp;
    public NativeArray<float> timestampArr; // only for storage
    public NativeList<int2> result;

    [ReadOnly] public float2 gridCenter;
    [ReadOnly] public float cellSize;

    public void Execute()
    {
        float rate = cellSize / 4f;

        result.Add(WorldToCell(A, gridCenter, cellSize));
        result.Add(WorldToCell(B, gridCenter, cellSize));
        result.Add(WorldToCell(C, gridCenter, cellSize));
        result.Add(WorldToCell(D, gridCenter, cellSize));

        SampleLine(A, B, rate, ref result, gridCenter, cellSize);
        SampleLine(B, C, rate, ref result, gridCenter, cellSize);
        SampleLine(C, D, rate, ref result, gridCenter, cellSize);
        SampleLine(D, A, rate, ref result, gridCenter, cellSize);

        float2 AB = (B - A);
        float2 AB_normalized = math.normalize(AB);
        float2 DC_normalized = math.normalize(C - D);
        float length = math.sqrt(AB.x * AB.x + AB.y * AB.y);
        float current = rate;
        while (current < length)
        {
            float2 X = A + AB_normalized * current;
            float2 Y = D + DC_normalized * current;

            SampleLine(X, Y, rate, ref result, gridCenter, cellSize);
            current += rate;
        }

        timestampArr[0] = timestamp;
    }

    private static void SampleLine(float2 A, float2 B, float sampleRate, ref NativeList<int2> occupied, float2 gridCenter, float cellSize)
    {
        float2 AB = (B - A);
        float2 AB_scaled = math.normalize(AB) * sampleRate;
        float2 test = A + AB_scaled;
        float length = math.sqrt(AB.x * AB.x + AB.y * AB.y);
        float current = sampleRate;

        while (current < length)
        {
            int2 cell = WorldToCell(test, gridCenter, cellSize);
            // optimally i want to use a hashset here because .IndexOf is very slow
            if (occupied.IndexOf(cell) == -1) occupied.Add(cell);
            test += AB_scaled;
            current += sampleRate;
        }
    }

    public static int2 WorldToCell(float2 vector, float2 gridCenter, float cellSize)
    {
        return (int2)math.floor(-(gridCenter - vector) / cellSize);
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, how do I prevent the costly `NativeList` vs `List` conversion? Why is adding a `NativeList` to a `NativeHashMap` slower than converting a `NativeList` to a `List` and adding that list to a `Dictionary`?

Also, would it maybe be better to split the job up into smaller jobs, since I could call `SampleLine` and even `WorldToCell` in parallel? But then I have no idea if jobs can start other jobs, or if I should just make `WorldToCell` a job (since it's called the most) and do the rest in normal C#? I'm completely new to the job system, so I have no idea what is supposed to be "jobbed" how. I could leave it as is with one big job, I could make lots of small jobs with `WorldToCell` or I could make all three calculation a job.

Comment: Going to take sometime to go through all of this, but I would recommend using meaningful variable names A B C D doesn't really help give an idea of what its use for.

Comment: @Eddge ABCD are the corners of the rectangle.

Comment: Have you tried setting target list capacity when initializing it? Since you already know the size of what it should be, you could set the capacity before adding elements. That way, there will be no need to resize the internal array when adding elements.

Comment: @Immorality the only time when I know the size beforehand is when initializing `List<int2> coordinates`. I could initialize the other lists with estimates to at least try reducing resizing by a few times. Or do you mean iterating over `resultList` first to count all the sizes and initialize the `NativeHashMap` or `Dictionary` with the correct size?

Comment: Hmm I was under the impression you knew the size of all the collections beforehand. If that is not the case and you cannot use a length or count property (not method) then it will probably do little for performance